# Why can't I get the system region on Xiaomi devices?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, region, xiaomi

On every other device I can use

```
Locale.Default.ISO3Country
```

to get the current region of the device, but for some reason on Xiaomi devices it always returns the region set in the Language options(I tried some different methods as well to get the region/country, all with the same result).

So for example if I set the Language to English(United Kingdom), and the Region of the device to Germany, my App (coded in Xamarin Android) will return the following for Xiaomi devices:

```
Language: English
Country: United Kingdom
```

and for any other device:

```
Language: English
Country: Germany
```

Does anyone know how to get the system region set in the options of Xiaomi devices, or even some way to get the region that works on all devices the same?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, did you find a possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Xiaomi divice always have weird issue like this.

yes you can get current reason with TelephonyManager

```
TelephonyManager tm  = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
```

Comment: Hi, your answer gives me the network country, but I need the country I set in the phone settings. So if i'm currently in Spain, and my system region is Germany, your solution would return me "Spain", but i need Germany.

Comment: try Locale.getDefault().getCountry()

Comment: That's not it, it returns "GB".

Comment: @cymenx  hey, String region =  System.getProperty("user.region");

        Toast.makeText(this, ""+ region, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   try this or if your device is rooted than check what xoami use as key to store region value and retrieve it back by same key ☹️☹️

Comment: The returned string is empty (I tried sys.region as well) :/, and my device is not rooted...